# How to set XChat spell checking to use a different language from the system default?

Tags: ubuntu, spell-check, xubuntu, xchat, aspell

I'm using Xubuntu 10.10. The system's language is not English (actually it is Hungarian), however I would like to use English spell checking with XChat. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After years of struggle, I think I found a solution. By starting XChat as `LANG=hu:en xchat` it seems working the way I want it. For now.

The answer came from: 
http://toxin.jottit.com/xchat_spell_checking